# Installing ASP.net DNX with Powershell 2.0

Tags: asp.net, powershell, dnx

I am trying to get an install of ASP.Net DNX on Windows. I followed the instructions at: https://github.com/aspnet/home#cmd

The problem is. when I run this, I get an error stating:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\parsonsjm0818\Desktop>@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestric
ted -Command "&{$Branch='dev';iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('ht
tps://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}"
Using temporary directory: C:\Users\PARSON~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dnvminstall
Downloading DNVM.ps1 to
Downloading DNVM.cmd to
Installing DNVM
The script 'dnvm.ps1' cannot be run because it contained a "#requires" statemen
t at line 2 for Windows PowerShell version 3.0. The version required by the scr
ipt does not match the currently running version of Windows PowerShell version
2.0.
At line:1 char:191
+ [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ''; [System.Threadi
ng.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = '';$CmdPathFile='C:\Users\parsonsj
m0818\.dnx\temp-set-envvars.cmd';& <<<<  'C:\Users\PARSON~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
dnvminstall\dnvm.ps1' setup
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (dnvm.ps1:String) [], Scrip
   tRequiresException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptRequiresUnmatchedPSVersion


C:\Users\parsonsjm0818\Desktop>
```

Can I install the DNX with only Powershell 2.0 or do I have to upgrade to 3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`The script 'dnvm.ps1' cannot be run because it contained a "#requires" statemen
t at line 2 for Windows PowerShell version 3.0.`

If you want to be sure that the script will work, you'll have to use Powershell v3.0.  It is certainly possible to modify the script to remove the requirement, but it as probably put there for a good reason.  It would just be a roll of the dice if it would actually work if the requirement was removed.

Comment: Do you have any idea of what I would have to modify in the script for it to work?

Comment: No, you will need to ask whoever wrote the script.